# splice with only one parameter not deleting the whole array

Tags: javascript

```js
a = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
console.log(a.splice(1));
console.log(a);
```

In splice documentation, it says that skipping the delete parameter will delete all array items, yet here they're not; the first one is left out. Why is this?

Edit: My expectations was that haveing the omission of the delete parameter would cause to delete all the items of the array. But now after read Baconnier comment I understand that removes all after the index (first parameter).

> then all the elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted. start being 1 in your case.

Comment: _then all the elements from `start` to the end of the array will be deleted._ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice `start` being 1 in your case.

Comment: Well arrays start at 0 so why would it delete "a" when you use 1?

Comment: Can you please update your question with your **expected** results vs. **actual** results?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
console.log(a.splice(0));
console.log(a);
```

Arrays start at 0, if you want to delete all elements including the first one you need to pass 0 as the first parameter.